# Trying to get lookup (Title) value, but returns null only in Client Object Model

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, lookup-column

I have this query:

```
<View>                                             
    <ViewFields>
        <FieldRef Name='Title' />
        <FieldRef Name='itlgCategoria'/>
    </ViewFields>
</View>
```

**itlgCategoria** is a lookup field

When I use CAML query Builder i get this:

[image]

My list have 2 rows.

If I try to get the ID from lookup field (**Conexao.oList.get_item('itlgCategorias').get_lookupID();**) i have the output:
    ;

```
1
5
```

But if I try to get the Value (**Conexao.oList.get_item('itlgCategorias').get_lookupValue();**) from lookup field i have the output:

```
null
null
```

I need to get **Achados e Perdidos** and **Campanhas**

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is this people and group column?

Comment: No. Custom category column. Category list have only one displayed column: Title, and I need to get this value.

Comment: In your lookup column settings (in list settings) what does it say under 'In this column:' ? Title or ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error.

My list only have the ID information.

Sharepoint understand that the value information is in the other list that I didnt have permission to read in my App.

**When I added "Web" permission in my AppManifest file, sharepoint allows me to access the Value of lookup column.**